# Does this plane geometry theorem have a name (well-known)?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, terminology, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Consider three circles $(O_1)$, $(O_2)$, $(O_3)$. Denote the homothetic center of $\{$$(O_1)$, $(O_2)$$\}$ by $A$, the homothetic center of $\{$$(O_2)$, $(O_3)$$\}$ by $B$. Let $C$, $D$ be two points on the line $AB$. Then the tangent lines from $C$ to $(O_3)$ and the tangent lines from $D$ to $(O_1)$ form a tangential quadrilateral, i.e. they are all tangent to some circle $(O_4)$, as in the figure.

Does this theorem have a name?

[image]

**See also:**

- Wikipedia on [Monge's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge%27s_theorem)

Comment: Partial cases: 6.2.9 and 6.2.11 are given without source in "Geometry in Figures" by A. Akopyan (the older free version has the first case 6.2.8 https://users.mccme.ru/akopyan/papers/EnGeoFigures.pdf)

Comment: Thanks You very much